# Expand child div to parent's height?

Tags: html, css

I have div which height I want to set same as the parent div height. 
This is what I want: [Jpg example](http://trayan.co.uk/test/1.jpg)

This is example code:

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="header">111</div>
<div id="menu">222</div>
<div id="content">333</div>
</div>
```

Parent has height: 100%. I want menu div (the grey one) to expand to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: You're looking for create equal height columns — http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Comment: @Terry : you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Not exactly I need #header to be expanded to the bottom of the screen even if the content is shorter. tried to set its min-height to 100% but didn't worked out.

Comment: Try searching next time.  This is probably the most common CSS question on the internet.  There are a lot of ways to do it depending on what your layout needs to accomplish... but literally just click ANY of the links under the "Related" area in the sidebar.

Comment: @Trayan This might help you. http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: What @Ennui said. In fact, I would go as far as to read anything with more than 20 votes. You'll learn a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The "One True Layout" method is my favorite when it comes to pure CSS...oldy but a goody
http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/print.html

```
#one-true { overflow: hidden; }
#one-true .col {
      width: 50%; //or whatever
      padding: 30px 10% 0; //or whatever
      float: left; 
      margin-bottom: -99999px; //important!
      padding-bottom: 99999px; //important!
}
#one-true .col:nth-child(1) { margin-left: 33.3%; background: #ccc; }
#one-true .col:nth-child(2) { margin-left: -66.3%; background: #eee; }
#one-true .col:nth-child(3) { left: 0; background: #eee; }
#one-true p { margin-bottom: 30px; } /* Bottom padding on col is busy */
```

Just make sure you assign a common class to any elements you want this height applied to.
You could also use jQuery to achieve the same end, which is how I do it if I need to make sure they are the same height programmatically.

To select immediate children:

```
$('#parent > div').height($('.col').height());
```

Or all children:

```
$('.col').children('*').height($('.col').height()); // be careful with borders and padding!
```